# ComboBox items.count doesn't match DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox that is bound to a DataSource. I want to dynamically add items to the ComboBox based on certain conditions. So what I've done is add the options to a new list, and then change the DataSource of the ComboBox like so:

```
cbo.DataSource = null;
cbo.DataSource = cbos;
cbo.DisplayMember = "Title";
cbo.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Then, I check `cbo.Items.Count`, and it has not incremented - it does not equal the count of the DataSource. Any ideas what I can do here?

Note this is WinForms and not ASP.NET.

Comment: Did you check the .Count property before or after the dropdown was actually dropped down? I suspect there's some optimizations being done to avoid reloading the items collection too often, so it might postpone the whole thing until you actually drop it down on-screen.

Comment: Which version of .NET is this? In Visual Studio 2008, compiling for either 2.0 or 3.5 produces the correct number of items at once.

Comment: I get this problem in VS2012 with a dynamically created combobox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If anyone experiences this problem on a dynamically added combobox, the answer is to ensure that you add the combobox to the controls of a container in the form.

By adding "this.Controls.Add(cbo);" to the code before setting the datasource, the problem goes away.

Comment: -1, untrue. It happens also if the ComboBox already is contained in a container that does not have a Windows handle yet.

Comment: I don't think that a -1 is fair here, just because you have found another reason that this occurs. This answer solved the problem in the stated example.

Comment: Unable to undo unless answer is edited. I keep wondering what kind of edititing rules are behind so's frontend...

Answer (score 12):

Did you check the Count immediately or at a later time?  There is the possibility that the ComboBox does not actually update it's contents until there is an operation such as a UI refresh and hence the count will be off until that time.

On case where this may happen is if you update the DataSource before the Handle is created for the ComboBox.  I dug through the code a bit on reflector and it appears the items will not be updated in this case until the ComboBox is actually created and rendered.

Comment: I'm checking the Items.Count property immediately after in code, because I need to then do some more logic at that point.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to check the number of items in your data source?

Comment: The problem is that I have to set the selected item, usually to the new one, and that index doesnt exist.

Comment: Came across this issue again somewhere else in code. The issue is that the combo box is being added at run time and therefore as Jared mentioned, no handle has been created for the combo box. By adding "this.Controls.Add(cbo);" the problem disappears.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the cause...

I took out the cbo.Datasource = null line.. and added a cbo.Invalidate() at the end. This has solved the problem.

Thanks all for the advice.

Comment: Found your own solution. Go ahead and accept your own answer. +1

Comment: You should have rather added this line before setting the datasource. `cbo.Items.clear()`

Answer (score 4):

```
cbo.DataSource = null; 
cbo.DataSource = cbos; 
cbo.DisplayMember = "Title"; 
cbo.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Now before setting `cbo.SelectedValue`, or relying on `Items` to be up-to-date, call

```
cbo.CreateControl ;
```

and `Items` will be re-calculated.

The problem is that `SelectedValue`/`SelectedIndex`, which are WinForms properties, only accept the values that are legal according to the `Items` list, but that one is built only after GUI interaction, i.e. after instantiating a "real" Windows GUI combo box, i.e. after obtaining a Windows handle for the combobox.

`CreateControl` forces the creation of the Windows handle, no matter what.

Comment: CreateControl did not fix the problem for me.  Adding the control to the collection did.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ComboBox cbNew = new ComboBox();
    cbNew.Name = "cbLine" + (i+1);
    cbNew.Size = cbLine1.Size;
    cbNew.Location = new Point(cbLine1.Location.X, cbLine1.Location.Y + 26*i);
    cbNew.Enabled = false;
    cbNew.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    cbNew.DataSource = DBLayer.GetTeams(lineName).Tables[0];
    cbNew.DisplayMember = "teamdesc";
    cbNew.ValueMember = "id";
    Console.WriteLine("ComboBox {0}, itemcount={1}", cbNew.Name, cbNew.Items.Count);
        // The output displays itemcount = 0 for run-time created controls
        // and >0 for controls created at design-time
    gbLines.Controls.Add(cbNew);
```

TO

```
 ComboBox cbNew = new ComboBox();
    cbNew.Name = "cbLine" + (i+1);
    cbNew.Size = cbLine1.Size;
    cbNew.Location = new Point(cbLine1.Location.X, cbLine1.Location.Y + 26*i);
    cbNew.Enabled = false;
    cbNew.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    Console.WriteLine("ComboBox {0}, itemcount={1}", cbNew.Name, cbNew.Items.Count);
        // The output displays itemcount = 0 for run-time created controls
        // and >0 for controls created at design-time
    gbLines.Controls.Add(cbNew);
    cbNew.DataSource = DBLayer.GetTeams(lineName).Tables[0];
    cbNew.DisplayMember = "teamdesc";
    cbNew.ValueMember = "id";
```

The DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember property must be set after the control has been added to its container.

Answer (score 1):

```
By adding "this.Controls.Add(cbo);" to the code before setting the datasource, the problem goes away.   
 //Create dynamic combobox and add to Panel
    ComboBox ddCombo = new ComboBox();
    controls = new Control[1] { ddCombo };
    panel.Controls.AddRange(controls); 

    //After creating add to table layout
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panel, 0, 0);

    ddCombo .Name = "ddName";
    ddCombo .Width = 200;
    ddCombo .Location = new Point(x, y);                                                                                                          ddCombo .DataSource = ds;//or any List
    ddCombo .SelectedIndex = ddCombo .Items.Count - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify are you calling the count() method
After calling the databind() method

Comment: This is a winforms combobox, there's no databind()

Answer (score 0):

This code produces 2 in the message box for me, can you try it and see how it behaves for you?

You can paste it into a console application, and add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace SO887803
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Button _Button;
        private ComboBox _ComboBox;

        public MainForm()
        {
            _Button = new Button();
            _Button.Text = "Test";
            _Button.Location = new Point(8, 8);
            _Button.Click += _Button_Click;
            Controls.Add(_Button);

            _ComboBox = new ComboBox();
            _ComboBox.Location = new Point(8, 40);
            Controls.Add(_ComboBox);
        }

        private void _Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item("A", "a"));
            items.Add(new Item("B", "b"));

            _ComboBox.DataSource = null;
            _ComboBox.DataSource = items;
            _ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Title";
            _ComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
            MessageBox.Show("count: " + _ComboBox.Items.Count);
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public String Title { get; set; }
            public String Value { get; set; }
            public Item(String title, String value)
            {
                Title = title;
                Value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

comboBox1.DataSource=somelist;

int c1=comboBox1.DataSource.Count; // still zero

BindingContext dummy = this.comboBox1.BindingContext;// Force update NOW!

int c2=comboBox1.DataSource.Count; // now it equals somelist.Count

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Im working with VS 2005).

What you need to do is set the DataSource to null, clear the items, reassign the datasource , display and value members.

Eg

cbo.DataSource = null;

cbo.Items.Clear();

cbo.DataSource = cbos;

cbo.DisplayMember = "Title";

cbo.ValueMember = "Value";

Comment: Works only if the ComboBox already has obtained a Windows handle.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I tried some of these solutions, along with suspending/resuming the bindingcontext, binding to and resetting a binding source, and just plain reloading the form.  None worked to update my control with the newly bound data at the time of my .datasource setting (my items.count was empty, just like the OP).

Then I realized that my combobox was on a tabpage that was getting removed at the start of the code, and later re-added (after my databinding).  The binding event did not occur *until* the tabpage was re-added.

Seems obvious in retrospect, but it was very difficult to detect at runtime, due to the order of calls and inability to see when things were changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
cbo.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
cbo.DataSource = null;
cbo.DataSource = cbos;
cbo.DisplayMember = "Title";
cbo.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Maybe your ComboBox`s BindingContext is null.

Answer (score -1):

Ba salam,

you can simply refresh the UI by preformLayout() function;

Example:

comboBox1.performLayout();

regards
mohsen s

Answer (score -1):

please try this:

```
cbo.Parent = <your panel control>;
cbo.DataSource = null; 
cbo.DataSource = cbos; cbo.DisplayMember = "Title"; 
cbo.ValueMember = "Value";
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("itemcount is {0}", cbo.Items.Count);
```

I think your question sames like I met today.