# ComboBox.Items.IndexOf always return -1

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

I create a `ComboBox` at runtime and I set the `DataSource` to Generic list. When I call the `combobBox.Items.IndexOf` to set `SelectedIndex` property, it always return `-1`. The value is contained in the `DataSource`, so it should be able to find the Index.

This is an example of the code that I use.

```
Private Function InitDomainCombo(ByVal value as object, ByVal domainList As List(Of DomainNameValue)) As ComboBox
    Dim cb As ComboBox

    cb = New ComboBox
    cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    cb.DataSource = domainList
    cb.DisplayMember = "Name"

    cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.IndexOf(CType(value, DomainNameValue))

    Return cb
End Function
```

Comment: Apparently, it's not there

Comment: I've already make the check with domainList.Contains(CType(value, DomainNameValue)) to make sure the value is in domainList

Comment: Did you try cb.Items.Contains(CType(value, DomainNameValue))

Comment: Could it be possible that the `Items` collection is empty? I'm not sure when the `ComboBox` will pull the objects from its data source into its `Items` collection, maybe that hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you try to select an item that doesn't exist yet.

Try :

- to add the `combobox` to your form before you set the `selectedIndex`.
- **or** force the initialization of the control using `combox.CreateControl()` method before you set the `selectedIndex`.

This thread is related to a similar issue : [ComboBox items.count doesnt match datasource (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887803/combobox-items-count-doesnt-match-datasource-c)

Comment: I changed the DataSource to Adding the objects directly to the ComboBox. Couldn't user the combox.CreateControl() since the ComboBox is part usercontrol that is in the process of begin created.