# Winforms: Number of items in the combobox not matching with the datasource of the same combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

I am using the following code to create Combobox.

```
ComboBox comboBox1 = new ComboBox() { Left = 101, Top = 35, Width = 121, Height = 21 };
this.list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("None");
list1.AddRange(listMain);
comboBox1.DataSource = list1;
```

After this I am not able to set the SelectedItem or SelectedValue or SelectedIndex for the comboBox.

And while debugging, I find that after all of the above 5 lines being executed, the watch window shows the following:
Name: list1
Value: Count = 1

Name: ComboBox1
Value: {System.Windows.Forms.Combobox, Items.Count: 0}

Name: ComboBox1.DataSource
Value: Count = 1

Note that initially listMain will be empty, but I am adding "None", so list1 is always gonna have a minimum 1 count.

How is it possible to have different count for a combobox items and its datasource?

Screenshot of the watch window here :
[image]

Comment: Here is an answer/s for the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887803/combobox-items-count-doesnt-match-datasource

Comment: Thanks, adding the combobox control to the form before assigning datasource worked.

Comment: [ComboBox.SelectedValue is null in the Form's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62382640/7444103)